# How to select records by ADDING its own rows using sql query for PHP MYSQL use

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble finding a solution for this question. Suggest any solution for this question in PHP.

I have a table called test_repeat

```
id  start   repeater   length     final
 1   20       2           3         50
 2   10       50          4        500
```

and my query is

```
SELECT T.id AS ID, T.start AS start, T.repeater AS repeater 
       T.length AS length, T.final AS final
FROM `test_repeater` T
RIGHT JOIN `test_repeater` T2 ON T.id = T2.id 
WHERE T.start>=10 and T2.start*T2.repeater<=300
```

the result i'm getting is

```
ID  start  repeater   length    final    
1   20       2          3        50       
2   10       5          12       500
```

What I am trying to get is the result in such a way that the each start value is added with the repeater and that makes that value as next raw until the final the conditions apply (please see below)

My dream result will be like this

```
   ID   start   repeater   length     final
   1     20       2           3         50
   1     22       2           3         50
   1     24       2           3         50
   1     ...      .           .         ...
   1     ...      .           .         ...
   1     50       2           3         50
   2     10       5           4         500
   2     15       5           4         500
   2     20       5           4         500
   2     25       5           4         500
   2     30       5           4         500
   2     35       5           4         500
   2     ...      .           .         ...
   2     ...      .           .         ...
   2     ...      .           .         ...
   2     500      5           4         500
```

Comment: Some of the thread titles make me feel dizzy

Comment: try with `UNION` instead of `right join`

Comment: 10 * 5 = 50, but then how do you get to 100?

Comment: @asprin i am soo sorry my friend

Comment: @jcho360 mate i hope union will do the job but please give me some more clues ...thanks soo much

Comment: @Strawberry mate that was a mistake from my side i have edited the question now..please suggest some idea.. thanks for your comment

Comment: can you put your table and info in www.sqlfiddle.com and we will make the query for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. That makes more sense...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_repeat;

 CREATE TABLE test_repeat
 (id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,start   INT NOT NULL
 ,repeater   INT NOT NULL
 ,length     INT NOT NULL
 ,final INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO test_repeat VALUE
 (1,   20       ,2           ,3         ,50),
 ( 2   ,10       ,5          ,4        ,500);


 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ints;

 CREATE TABLE ints(i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

 INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);



 SELECT r.id
      , r.start+(r.repeater*(i2.i*10+i1.i)) start
      , repeater
      , length
      , final 
   FROM test_repeat r 
   JOIN ints i1
   JOIN ints i2
  WHERE r.start+(r.repeater*(i2.i*10+i1.i)) BETWEEN r.start AND r.final
  ORDER 
     BY id
      , start;
```

Comment: mate now i found the result from this getting is almost same but not exact i found 2 abnormality (1)..its not starting from the exact table's start value, (2)..when its come to the next ID the result row starts from where the previous ID value stops.. (((for easy use))-->>  ID 1's record should start from 20 (+2 s) to 50 [50records] and ID 2's record start from 10 (+5 s) to 500 [100records]..so total 150(apr.)records... man can you please make any move to reach there...thanx in advance..

Comment: Did you see how I provided DDLs (CREATE and INSERT statements) for others to follow along? Do that, and show the desired result alongside as before.

Comment: yeah i did that too still i am not able to get reach into final .. please kindly do something more..thanx

Comment: i am getting exatct resul on this link ...on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2445a/1  ...but not getting in my localhost...any idea..thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT T.id AS ID, T.start*T.repeater AS mymultipliedstart, 
           T.length AS length, T.final AS final
    FROM `test_repeater` T
    RIGHT JOIN `test_repeater` T2 ON T.id = T2.id 

WHERE T.start>=10 and T2.start*T2.repeater<=300
```